# Why do we have the absorption edge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics

I am very puzzled by the **discontinuity of any physical quantity**.

If the energy of the photon is smaller than the excitation energy of the atom, the absorption rate is zero; if the energy of the photon is higher than or equal to the excitation energy, the absorption rate is finite.

Why does not the absorption rate start increasing from zero, namely, why is it not in the law of $ \propto (E_{photon}- E_{excitation})^\alpha $ for some $\alpha$?

[image]

Comment: If the photon energy is smaller than energy required to make the electron transition then the electron transition does not happen and the photon is not absorbed.

Comment: But why should it start from a finite value when the energy is bigger than the gap?

Comment: Do you mean by that why does the edge not go right down to zero absorption.  That is becasue the graph is showing the combined effect of three absorbers, Carbon, Nitrogen and Oxygen.  There are also other mechanisms by which the photons can be absorbed.

Comment: The previous comments (and answers) have missed the point, I think;  the question is asking "Is this transition really discontinuous?  Shouldn't it obey a power-law relationship?" I dare say that it should be continuous (the volume of accessible phase space increases continuously from zero as we pass the threshold energy), but presumably the scale of the "rise" is so small that it looks like a sharp edge over the scale of the entire spectrum.  Hopefully someone who knows more than I do about scattering processes can write a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an atomic system with nucleus and bound electrons; as the  atomic number increases, so does the number of electrons. The resulting electronic structure is quite complicated, but can be usefully described in terms of a number of shells.

When probing this atomic structure with photons of increasing energies it was soon discovered that there are energy bands where the x-ray absorption coefficient declining smoothly, but with sudden jumps. These are the x-ray edges.

What is happening?  The increasing energies applied have been shuffling things around in the outer electron shells, but as they probe deeper  they don't fit the landscape as well, and thus the falling absorption coefficient.  Then the energy matches the binding energy for the next inner shell - essentially a resonance match- and the x-ray edge appears.

See http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_2/4_2_1.html